# Cómo puedo llamar con JavasScript a una imagen desde un elemento en XML con atributo

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Estoy intentando llamar a una imagen que está insertada dentro de un elemento XML que tiene un atributo. He conseguido hacer funcionar el script con un elemento que no tiene atributo. A continuación voy a poner el script y el XML simplificados para que sea más fácil de entender.

**XML que he conseguido hacer funcionar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST_GROUP>
    <TEST>
        <TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
        <imageurl>imagen.jpg<imageurl>
    </TEST>

</TEST_GROUP>
```

**Script que funciona:**

```
<script>
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<table border='10'>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TEST");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("imageurl")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.write(img.src);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    document.write("</table>");


</script>
```

**XML que quiero hacer funcionar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST_GROUP>
    <TEST>
        <TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
        <imageurl ruta="imagen.jpg"/>


    </TEST>

</TEST_GROUP>
```

He intentado meter en el elemento de llamada la ruta, pero no ha habido manera. Sé que el secreto está en este punto

```
img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("imageurl")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Que hay que sustituir el elemento **"imageurl"** por el de **ruta**, pero es imposible. O al menos yo no he sido capaz.

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes el método `getAttribute` para leer los atributos de un elemento.

Así debería funcionarte.

```
img.src = x[i].getElementsByTagName("imageurl")[0].getAttribute('ruta');
```

Comment: Pense que en XML no se podían crear atributos personalizados, puesto que es mas estricto, que bueno saber entonces que si se puede.

Comment: @Riven para setear tienes el método `setAttribute ` este es para hacer get de un atributo.

Comment: Si hawks gracias por la info, lo sabia pero lo que no sabia es que se podía tener atributos personalizados, muy interesante la verdad...

Comment: Ha funcionado. Muchas gracias